# The Difference between Sliced DataFrame and Read DataFrame in File when Merging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a deleted row from two dataframes (previous, current).

The previous dataframe is a slice of the entire data,
The current dataframe is read from the csv file

type 1 : merge sliced dataframe

```
  <type 1>
  import pandas as pd

  data_all = pd.read_csv("./result/data_2010-202002.csv", index_col=0)

  # 2019.12, 2020.1, 2020.2(data slicing)
  data_0 = data_all.loc[(data_all['year'] == 2019) & (data_all['month'] == 12)]
  data_1 = data_all.loc[(data_all['year'] == 2020) & (data_all['month'] == 1)]
  data_2 = data_all.loc[(data_all['year'] == 2020) & (data_all['month'] == 2)]

  # concatenate                                                    
  previous_data = pd.concat([data_0, data_1, data_2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

  # updated file readning
  current_data = pd.read_csv("./result/data_201912-202002.csv", index_col=0)

  # merge how='outer'
  data_merged = pd.merge(previous_data, current_data, how = 'outer', indicator = True)

  # deleted row(The row in current_data is not in previous_data)
  data_merged.loc[data_merged._merge == "left_only"]
```

======================================================================

type 2 : Save the sliced data frame into a file, read it again and merge

```
  <type 2>

  previous_data = pd.concat([data_0, data_1, data_2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

  # save dataframe as file
  previous_data.to_csv('./result/data_201912-202002_split.csv', mode='w')

  # read dataframe in file
  previous_data = pd.read_csv("./result/data_201912-202002_split.csv", index_col=0) 

  # updated file readning
  current_data = pd.read_csv("./result/data_201912-202002.csv", index_col=0)

  # merge how='outer'
  data_merged = pd.merge(previous_data, current_data, how = 'outer', indicator = True)

  # deleted row(The row in current_data is not in previous_data)
  data_merged.loc[data_merged._merge == "left_only"]
```

There is a big difference in the results of type 1 and type 2.

I want to know why.

For reference, the case of type2 printed out more accurate results.

thank you